# Solr (4.6.1) re-ordering by custom field value before response

Tags: solr

Let say I have a serval documents like below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": "Low",
    "summary": ".."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "priority": "Medium",
    "summary": ".."
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "priority": "High",
    "summary": ".."
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "priority": "High",
    "summary": ".."
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "priority": "Low",
    "summary": ".."
},
... other documents ...
```

If I issue a query, Solr return the document order

```
1 (score 282)
4 (score 212)
5 (score 182)
2 (score 25)
3 (score 13)
```

sort by score desc which is ok.

Right now I still need to sorting by score first, but the additional requirement is:

```
for each score segments, re-order the document using the document priority.
```

I know this is a bit confusing and not clear about "score segments", but theoretically I want to apply 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range
to those result score and separate the segments into

```
x >= 0.7
x < 0.7 &  x > 0.3
x <= 0.3
```

And I will take min score = 0, so the normalised score will be

```
1 (normalised score 1)    (segment 1)
4 (normalised score 0.75) (segment 1)
5 (normalised score 0.64) (segment 2)
2 (normalised score 0.08) (segment 3)
3 (normalised score 0.04) (segment 3)
```

The result I want to achieve is re-order each segment so that result become

```
4 -> 1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2
instead of
1 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 3
```

I am looking into the Function Query, Custom Plugin. It seems Plugin can get the result document score, but I am not sure how to re-order the documents.

I would appreciate some pointers on this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CustomScoreQuery and CustomScoreProvider. Add an integer priority  field with values (high=3, medium=2, low=1) into your document in order to cache and use it in scoring computation.

```
public class MyScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {

    private FieldCache.Ints priorities;

    public MyScoreProvider(AtomicReaderContext context) throws IOException {
        super(context);
        priorities = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getInts(context.reader(), "priority_numeric", false);
    }

    public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore) {

        int segment = 100 / getSegmentNumber(subQueryScore);
        return segment + priorities.get(doc);

    }
}
```

Also consider to write QParserPlugin for using CustomScoreQuery. See this link for more information. http://spykem.blogspot.com/2013/06/plug-in-external-score-to-solr.html

Comment: Thank you, may I ask is subQueryScore already applied query time boost? 

And it seems not possible to get the maxScore of this query search so in which way I can implement the getSegmentNumber(subQueryScore) method?

Comment: Yes, subQueryScore is already applied boost. And it is not possible to get maxScore, but I can suggest you for each query to use the maxScore of the previous one or if it will not work. to do double query each time by writing custom SearchComponent.